# Is it possible to search in comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, search

Is it possible to search in comments, along with searching in questions and answers?  I suspect the answer is *no*.  I think that would be a very useful option to have in the advanced search.

Comment: For what would that be a useful option? Comments generally are transient and should not carry vital information.

Comment: For example--sometimes they have useful links that are not in the answers.

Comment: @user45664 In such cases, those links should be added to the answers. (By "useful" I assume you mean "useful to be included in the answer")

Comment: @David Z  How to add to another's answer if not via a comment?

Comment: @user45664 By _editing_. Comments do not add to answers; edits do. (Or, if the author of the answer really doesn't want the links in their answer, you can always post your own, separate answer that includes them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no on-site mechanism owning to the intentionally second-class status of comments.

When I really must search comments I use google with the `site:physics.stackexchange.com` specifier, but you often have to search through a very large number of results. The more comprehensive the list of keywords you can provide the better. Also include the username if you know it (say when searching your own comments).

Comment: Do you think there would be any chance of getting this implemented?

Comment: No, *"owning to the intentionally second-class status of comments"*.

Comment: FWIW, using the google hack with `site:` is how I search for anything on this site... the built-in search is not great. Unless I have enough information like `is:Q` and the username I'm looking for or something.

Comment: If one goes through a lot of effort to find something useful useful in a comment, one might take the initiative to edit that useful information into the attached post (he said in a comment)

Comment: @rob  via an answer?

Comment: @user45664 Or by editing the answer under which the comment appears. Depends on the context. A lot of comments—though helpful—are not substantive enough to make a answer all on their own.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to dmckee's answer, which is generally quite reliable, if you can't find what you're looking for, then variants of [this Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/675047/comment-search) might help.