# Cannot find a question upon statistical mechanics I commented on

Tags: support, specific-question, comments, search

perhaps you can help me track down a question I commented on (cannot find my comments in my list). It was about the Heisenberg and Schrödinger pictures of classical mechanics. I remember telling the OP about the book by Balescu and promised him to find other sources.

I was now going to post an answer which would relieve the OP the pain of looking into books, but cannot find the question anymore.
Has something happened to it?

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9884/

Comment: @dmckee. No, I was not questioning on how to find comments. I know that. I was looking for the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the concrete case: *Yes,* the question [*Time evolution in classical statistical mechanics*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369905/2451) was deleted 2 days ago by [OP](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/62173/user929304) along with your comments.

In general: You cannot search comments with the SE search engine, but you e.g. can use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=danielc+heisenberg&as_sitesearch=https%3A%2F%2Fphysics.stackexchange.com) (if the comments have not been deleted). See also [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9884/2451) related meta post.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a shame then for OP, he/she is the one to lose. I don't need google to find my active/undeleted comments here. There is the "all actions" tab under the own profile and comments one has made and still available on the site are listed there.